# objective c HTTPS login. POST and get correct url status code

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, url, xcode5

Im having an issue returning 200 status code from the browser. Im trying to POST a url with the username and password to a url and get an xml response.

0 = wrong username/password
1 = success login

The correct url is :
https://apix.xxx.

incorrect url but still receiving 200 status code:
xxx.com

I believe the problem is the url not being built correctly

Even if the login is wrong i should get a 200 status code returned, but it only returns 404.

thanks for the help

```
- (IBAction)sigininClicked:(id)sender {
NSInteger success = 0;
@try {

    if([[self.txtUsername text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {

        [self alertStatus:@"Please enter Email and Password" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];

    } else {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",
                                           @"https://xxx.testauthenticate",
                                           self.txtUsername.text,
                                           self.txtPassword.text]];

        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", url];

        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);
        //NSLog(@"url: %@",url);

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

        if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
        {
            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

        } else {
            if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    [self alertStatus:@"Sign in Failed." :@"Error!" :0];
}
if (success) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
}
}
```

Comment: If you have found a solution to your question, please post it as an answer.  Adding it to the original question makes it harder to understand other answers, and may make it look like the question is unanswered for somebody browsing.  After a few days' wait, you can accept your own answer to close the question.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status code `404` means that requested endpoint doesn't exist.
As I see you use link `https://apix.pointstreak.com/performance/index.php/testauthenticate` that is invalid. Try to open it in browser and you will see error message `404 Page Not Found`.
Set correct url and it will work.

Update:
Try to change url string to this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", 
                                                             @"https://apix.pointstreak.com/performance/index.php/testauthenticate",
                                                             self.txtUsername.text,
                                                             self.txtPassword.text]];
```

Comment: the username and password are not being placed at the end of the url. or is being done incorrectly. I think thats the problem

Comment: @user3582441 in your example you set username and password to request body, but not to request url.

Comment: url appears to be correct but getting 405 status code now. Method Not Allowed